# BeautifulSoup: obtain div text under another tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm looking at the below html and I'm struggling to get the "Sondaż CBOS: KO z najgorszym wynikiem w historii" text and "https://www.rp.pl/Polityka/210519462-Sondaz-CBOS-Koalicja-Obywatelska-z-najgorszym-wynikiem-w-historii.html" link in the html below.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 news-block teaser-parent -visible -seen" data-dateid="2021-05-17">
   <div class="mk-small__wrapper" style="display: none;">
      <div class="ccesection">
         <div class="cce-object">
            <div class="hidden" data-info="No suitable cce objects form marketing component (cceclass: section_page, ccetype: promoblock_01)"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <article class="teaser teaser--photo-top ">
      <a href="https://www.rp.pl/Polityka/210519462-Sondaz-CBOS-Koalicja-Obywatelska-z-najgorszym-wynikiem-w-historii.html"><img class="teaser__image" src="/apps/pbcsi.dll/storyimage/RP/20210517/KRAJ/210519462/AR/0/0/AR-210519462.jpg?MaxW=370&amp;imageversion=Artykul&amp;lastModified=20210517160855"></a>
      <h4 class="teaser__index"><a href="/kraj/polityka">Polityka</a></h4>
      <a href="https://www.rp.pl/Polityka/210519462-Sondaz-CBOS-Koalicja-Obywatelska-z-najgorszym-wynikiem-w-historii.html">
         <div class="teaser__title">Sondaż CBOS: KO z najgorszym wynikiem w historii</div>
      </a>
      <div class="teaser__footer"> <time datetime="2021-05-17T16:08:55-03:00">17.05.2021, 16:08</time> , <a href="https://www.rp.pl/autor/1/1-mikulski">1 Mikulski</a></div>
      <div class="teaser__icon"></div>
   </article>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta

url='https://www.rp.pl/kraj'
response=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

for item in soup.select('.col-md-4'):
    headline = item.find('div', {'class':'teaser__title'}).get_text()
    link = item.find('a')['href']
```

I'm getting the NoneType error like it is not finding the element I'm after for the "headline" variable and getting some other links I'm not trying to refer to in the "link" variable. I'm clearly referencing the wrong items in the html.

I appreciate the help very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class="teaser__title"` are actually under `<h3>` tags, not `<div>`. Also, I woould go and grab all the `<article>` tags, rather than the `'.col-md-4'` class, as you get None again.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta

url='https://www.rp.pl/kraj'
response=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

items = soup.select('article')
for item in items:
    headline = item.select_one('.teaser__title').get_text()
    link = item.select_one('.teaser__title').find_previous('a')['href']
    print('%s\n%s\n\n' %(headline, link))
```

**Output:**

```
Poseł Porozumienia: „Nowy Ład” to program groźny dla Polski
https://www.rp.pl/Polityka/210519486-Posel-Porozumienia-Nowy-Lad-to-program-grozny-dla-Polski.html


Sondaż CBOS: KO z najgorszym wynikiem w historii
https://www.rp.pl/Polityka/210519462-Sondaz-CBOS-Koalicja-Obywatelska-z-najgorszym-wynikiem-w-historii.html


„Lewica i PO kłócą się o Polski Ład. A Kaczyński zaciera ręce”
https://podcasty.rp.pl/rzecz-w-tym/13393-lewica-i-po-kloca-sie-o-polski-lad-a-kaczynski-zaciera-rece?utm_source=rp&utm_medium=teaser_redirect


Budka: Thun powołuje się na racje z zamierzchłej przeszłości
https://www.rp.pl/Platforma-Obywatelska/210519454-Budka-o-Thun-Powoluje-sie-na-jakies-racje-z-zamierzchlej-przeszlosci.html


Cenna klacz nie wróciła do Janowa. „Słuch o niej zaginął”
https://www.rp.pl/Spoleczenstwo/305169953-Cenna-klacz-arabska-niczym-znikajacy-punkt.html


Braun: Nie będzie segregacji sanitarnej w Rzeszowie
https://www.rp.pl/Polityka/210519459-Braun-Nie-bedzie-segregacji-sanitarnej-w-Rzeszowie.html


Raś: Polski Ład to program PiS na wcześniejsze wybory...
https://www.rp.pl/RZECZoPOLITYCE/210519460-Ireneusz-Ras-Polski-Lad-to-program-PiS-na-wczesniejsze-wybory-parlamentarne.html
```